# Passing parameters into marionette component?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a marionette/backbone component I am trying to pass in parameters to to conditionally render elements in my .hbs template.

Something like so:

```
return Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: template,
    tagName: CustomElements.register('search-settings'),
    regions: {
        propertyResultCount: '.property-result-count',
        propertySearchSettings: '.property-search-settings'
    },
    events: {
        'click > .editor-properties > .editor-btn-group > .editor-save': 'triggerSave',
        'click > .editor-properties > .editor-btn-group > .editor-cancel': 'cancel'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.showSave();
    },
```

I'm rendering this view using:

```
this.settingsContent.show(new SearchSettings("search settings param"));
```

Is it possible to access this input parameter? I want to be able to pass in custom parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass object to constructor:

```
this.settingsContent.show(new SearchSettings({
    searchString: "search settings param"
}));
```

And access it in Marionette view via:

```
this.options.searchString
```

And/or pass it to template via: templateHelpers (https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.view.html#viewtemplatehelpers)